# Send email on every commit in private git

Tags: git, outlook

I have a query here is there any way we can configure exchange details in private git. Well in Github we do have this option of configuring it but i am using private git... Is there any such way we can send emails to specific set of people after each commits...

unfortunately I am not using Jenkins.

My Git server and Outlook is on Windows..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You might try githooks.com.  I believe they have an exact script for what you need.  It may be better to post if you are having a specific problem with a hook and need help making it work.

Comment: Hi Dennis... I didn't really tried githooks yet.. I will work on it and provide some inputs..I just wanted some clues on how to achieve it... Seems githooks should be the first one i should try..

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Assuming you have your own git server hosted and you have access to hooks.

What all you need is a post-receive hook, which will send email as soon as a git push is completed its execution.

Refer : https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks

You need something like this as a "post-receive" hook:

```
while read oldrev newrev refname;
do
    #Do something 
    mail -s "<Subject>" -r "<From>" "<To>"
done
```

Edit : I missed the part in question about having git on Windows. Above snippet will work on Unix. Not sure about equivalent command for mail in Windows.

Comment: @evolutionxbox git send-mail is about sending the git "patch" through mail. Its a command-line git and I guess can't be executed as a hook.

Answer (score 0):

[git sources](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/hooks) contains everything you need. See `post-receive-email` hook and `multimail/` subdirectory.